# erl -noshell -s module function argument not work

Tags: erlang

It's a weird problem.
When I call function without argument, it works.
See https://gist.github.com/kingluo/6e5245692b76dda5ecd4

I change the test2 as:

```
test2([N])->
    I = list_to_integer(atom_to_list(N)),
    max(I).
```

Because erl pass argument in atom type.
But I have two new questions:

- why test2 must use `[N]` but not just `N`?
- why max still runs with N
  in atom type? why not complain it's not integer type? What happens
  there? atom N is infinite integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arguments passed on the command line are always atoms, see the doc at http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html.

So test2/1 must convert the atom to a string and then to an integer.

Answer (score 1):

The -run option will pass arguments as strings, which can be converted to integer.